# Best way to create categories tree

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, loops

I need to create a category tree recursively searching a MySQL table.

My question is how to do it. I am trying using foreach in PHP. But I think that exists a way to do it just with a SQL query, like a loop.

The response I need is like this:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
            'slug' => 'value', 
            'title' => 'value', 
            'childs' => array(
                array(
                    'slug' => 'value', 
                    'title' => 'value', 
                    'childs' => array()
                ), 
                array(
                    'slug' => 'value', 
                    'title' => 'value', 
                    'childs' => array(
                        array(
                            'slug' => 'value', 
                            'title' => 'value', 
                            'childs' => array()
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
```

Any solution using SQL syntaxes or only with PHP loops?

My table design is in this print:

[image: Table: blog_categories]

Answer (score 1):

MySQL query will always return "flat" resultset without any nesting, so if you want to get nested arrays from SQL resultset, you have to get all categories and then postprocess it with PHP code to build your nested array.